# Call from a main of one class, a main method of another class

Tags: java, swing, syntax, server, java-server

I have two bearing classes - a GUI one and Server. They both have main() methods. When a 'connect' button (from class GUI) is clicked I want to start up all the processes in class Server, by starting from its main() function. Am I able to do that at all, is there a way to avoid it?

I've tired to:
 - Delete the main(String[] args) part of the Server class, rename it initServer and then through GUI to say

```
Server kb = new Server();
kb.initServer();`
```

- Say the following:

  `Server.main()` (in this case I kept both classes with main()s)

That is all I have right now, when clicked the Connect button its event takes place but all neither of the Server checks show up, in the command line.

Comment: The solution is not to have one class call the other's main, but to structure your code so that the one class can use instances of the other in an OOP-compliant manner. In other words, re-factor and improve the code base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
    private void run() {
        new Test2();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.run();
    }
}
```

**Test2.java**

```
public class Test2 {
    Test2() {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

Where when the function `run()` is executed in the first class, it executes the second class? In your case you would do this with an `ActionListener` and the second class would start your server

But to answer the question properly, *How can you call the main from another class?*, you can do it like this:

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
    private void run() {
        new Test2().main(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.run();
    }
}
```

**Test2.java**

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dan, it's not me who is down-voting.... back on the topic, I think I must try this out. It should be sth simular. It doesn't make sense I to keep the Server class as a main because it will execute only if a condition is true, so that means that my main() must be only in the GUI. I'll refine those both and I'll try what you've just adviced me. I was just working on both classes separately and now I came up to the point of joining them... it's only those two which mess up the whole thing, should be sth minor

Comment: @KDX2 If you don't want to cause too much trouble when rearranging classes if you look at the edit for my answer to method `new Server().main(null);` might allow it to work

Comment: @Dan, is it possible I to have started up the Server class but it to be the cmd which is not outputting? `private void jLabel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // this must start the server:
        new ServerSide().main(null);}`
That's how the GUI side looks like now, and Server:
`public static void main ServerSide (String[] args){
  System.out.println("U are in the server side"); +blablabla...}`
That second check - U are in the server side doesn't show

Comment: Does your server class run properly on its own?

Comment: @Dan, I've edited a bit my answer above. Yes, I can assure you that both classes are completely functional.

Comment: `"That second check - U are in the server side doesn't show"` -- where are you expecting to see it? In the GUI? Again, I see all this as being a kludge where you need to OOP-ify your server code so that it doesn't try to print Strings to standard output but rather can return Strings that can be used and seen in your GUI. Until you refactor, I think you're stuck.

Comment: @KDX2 Looking at the code above have you commented out the code to start the server in your gui class?

Comment: @Dan, no and static void main SERVERSIDE... is the same but without serverside, I've pasted a bit mistaken line here. No, it is not commented, it's just due to the formatting of the site here... I started developing the GUI on Netbeans but when it came up to joining the both cores, I found out that I am not able to debug in console, things like System.out...blabla don't work there and that if I want to debug at all I need to do it through netbeans's gui. So I switched back to Sublime but in order to know if everything is working well I think I need my console for now.

Comment: @KDX2: `"No, it is not commented, it's just due to the formatting of the site here..."` -- better to post new code as an edit to your original question rather than in comments, since as you're finding out, code loses its formatting in comments.

Comment: @KDX2: ... and we haven't yet even broached the subject of Swing threading and running long processes. No matter what solution you use, if you don't take this into consideration, say by using a `SwingWorker`, then your code will freeze and render useless the GUI.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, the gui is running in a simple JFrame, therefore the GUI class extends javax.swing.JFrame. There are bunch of labels, a text field, it is not anything special. On some events I load images which give a custom appearance to the buttons, I have a background image. as well. Everything is put in a loop:
`java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new KeyboardGUI().setVisible(true);
            }`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I have sorted it out. Now both classes initialize, and on button clicked the GUI starts the Server, the only problem is that I get a massive freeze on both but it is not related to the topic here :D

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, thank you so much! Actually to both of you, for the your patience and time. I have removed the man() from the Server class as well as the 'public void' part and instead I made it just a public function. Then on mouse event I make this: Server kb = new Server(); so now the server starts. When it is 'void' in front of the method name - no System.outs... so that was a thumb up for ommiting it. I will follow your advice, thank you!